# Error Prompt modifying cells using EpPlus

Tags: c#

I used the code below to allow me to modify the cell [J10] using EpPlus] The modify code work sucessfully but when I try to open the excel file I get prompted this error `We found a problem with some content in 'test.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click yes`. May I ask how about do I go past this error

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(fileLocation);

ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
//Add the Content sheet
var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();

//Headers
ws.Cells["J10"].Value = "TEST TIS";

pck.Save();
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileLocation);
```